# Repairing Hooks and Permissions in Migrated Gitolite Repo

Tags: gitolite

I had a gitolite pre-g2 repository I am attempting to get going on g3.

I copied over the entire repositories folder, and started with a clean g3 conf file, and removed all the gl-perms files to have a clean slate. I am trying to get a couple repos up and running with per-repo permissions.

Specifically I have my admin access keys and can clone and push the repo. This is defined the gitolite.conf as:

```
@admin = nikolaj

repo @all
    RW+ = @admin
```

Then for the individual repo, I made sure my name (nikolaj) was in the gl-creator file, and removed the old gl-perms file.

I then try to run

```
ssh git@myserver perms my/repo
```

and I get

```
FATAL: sorry you are not authorised
```

Any help on how I can go about debugging this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the [migration guide](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2migr.html) and did [preset your gitolite.rc file](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2migr.html#rc-preset)

> If you don't preset the rc (in this case, by commenting out the '`ssh-authkeys`' line) before running gitolite setup, your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file will get clobbered.

In your case, you did get a new gitolite.rc file, but still check if your  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is still intact (with a forced-command using `nikolaj` as parameter)